# Want to use SPI sensor in RS485 modbus

Tags: spi, rs485, esp32, imu, modbus

I want to use multiple ICM20948 over SPI to RS485 with esp32 . is there anyway to do it and also is there have any other IMU which support rs485?

Comment: Your IMU does not support MODBUS - it is the code on the esp32 that translates.  What is the problem with having multiple esp32/imu/rs485? Considering the esp32 is only a few USD, its not like it adds much to the cost.

Comment: You ask "is there anyway to do it" - yes there is. You connect your multiple ICM20948 devices to a SPI port on your ESP32, and you connect a UART in your ESP32 to an RS485 transceiver for it to talk MODBUS. Did you have a more specific question?